# Removing leading question marks from first two words of data frame entries in R

Tags: r

I have a large data frame in R with column "NameFull" holding a text string made up of two words (binomial scientific name), followed by author name(s) and initials. Both have been corrupted (presumably UTF translation issues). This means that in the binomials any leading "x" (indicating hybrids) has been replaced with "?". Unfortunately any non-standard characters in the author names have also been replaced with "?" so I cannot just replace all "?" with x.
I simply want to replace and leading "?" in the first two words with "x" (I will then have to manually compose a list of corrected author names to replace the corrupted ones, unless anyone has a bright idea on that!).

Example chunk of df:

```
df.corrupt <- data.frame(Bing = 1:6, FullName = c("?Anthematricaria dominii Rohlena", "?Anthemimatricaria inolens P.Fourn.", "?Anthemimatricaria maleolens P.Fourn.", "Achillea ?albinea Bjel?i? & K.Mal?", "Achillea carpatica B?ocki ex Dubovik", "Floscaldasia azorelloides Sklen ? & H.Rob."), Bang = 1:6)
```

I've tried to shoehorn it into regex but can't get close. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is the data corrupted when you pull it into R or corrupted in your raw data file? If the raw file has intact data you can also try `read.csv("data.txt", header= T, sep="\t", as.is = T, fileEncoding="UTF-16")` or whatever encoding the file has.

Comment: Note: when you open the dataframe in the viewer this may still show up incorrectly because the viewer may convert it to UTF-8 also. So try the viewer and the console to view whether the new input worked. `View(df)` or `str(df)` or `df[[1,1]]`

Comment: Thanks @AdamSampson, I should have clarified, the raw data is corrupt - and at this stage I have no way of getting my hands on a non-corrupt version :/
But that is a useful tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my understanding, you want to replace `?`only if it occurs in word-initial position in either the first or the second word; if that's correct this should work:

**Data:** (I've changed a few chars)

```
df.corrupt <- data.frame(Bing = 1:6, 
                         FullName = c("?Anthematricaria dominii ?Rohlena", 
                                      "?Anthemimatricaria inolens P.Fourn.", 
                                      "?Anthemimatricaria maleolens ?P.Fourn.", 
                                      "Achillea ?albinea Bjel?i? & K.Mal?", 
                                      "Achillea carpatica B?ocki ex Dubovik", 
                                      "Floscaldasia azorelloides Sklen ? & H.Rob."), Bang = 1:6)
```

**Solution:**

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(df.corrupt$FullName, "^\\?|(?<=^(\\?)?\\b\\w{1,100}\\b\\s)\\?", "x")
[1] "xAnthematricaria dominii ?Rohlena"          "xAnthemimatricaria inolens P.Fourn."       
[3] "xAnthemimatricaria maleolens ?P.Fourn."     "Achillea xalbinea Bjel?i? & K.Mal?"        
[5] "Achillea carpatica B?ocki ex Dubovik"       "Floscaldasia azorelloides Sklen ? & H.Rob."
```

This `stringr` solution puts `x` where `?`occurs right at the start of the string (`^`) or (`|`) using positive lookbehind (i.e., a non-consuming capturing group) where it follows a whitespace char (`\\s`), which in turn follows a word boundary (`\\b`) following up to 100 `\\w` chars following a word boundary, following finally an optional `?`

Comment: Hey @ChrisRuehlemann, thank you, works great when it's the first word in the binomial, but when it replaces an "?" in the second word (eg. "Achillea ?albinea") it removes the first word in the binomial (result is "xalbinea..." not "Achillea xalbinea...". Any ideas on a work-around for this?

Comment: Sorry I had posted an older result. The regex gives the correct updated result (now included in the post). For example: `"Achillea ?albinea Bjel?i? & K.Mal?"`becomes `"Achillea xalbinea Bjel?i? & K.Mal?"`!

Comment: Oh, brilliant! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

We can check for the `?` that succeeds a space or at the start of the string, replace with 'x'

```
trimws(gsub("(^|\\s)\\?", " x", df.corrupt$FullName))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, that works if the only leading "?"s are in the binomial (the first two words), but there are leading "?"s in the author names after that that I do not want to replace with an "x".
Apologies, I should have included one of those in my example set. Have edited it.

Comment: Does the `?` you want to replace always occur in word-initial position of either the first or the second word?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann it does! If "?" occurs in the first two words it is always the first character. It can occur anywhere in the subsequent words.